# Zurb foundation remove left padding from right div

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, padding, spacing

I'm not using SASS, I'm using CSS. How can I remove the left padding from the right div? I want to remove the left padding only for when it's showing the large size column, if its size is smaller than the large size, I want it to stay using the left-padding (for mobile purposes).

[example http://nsae01.casimages.net/img/2014/02/28/140228050513402376.jpg](http://nsae01.casimages.net/img/2014/02/28/140228050513402376.jpg)

Comment: provide your code and/or fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you set a class for all sibling containers (i.e. columns) and set:

```
DIV.myColumnClass:first-child {
    padding: 0px 20px; /* left and right padding */
}

DIV.myColumnClass {
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px; /* right padding */
} 

DIV.myColumnClass:last-child {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

It's somewhat different: the first column will have left and right padding, the other columns just the right one, the last one no left or right padding.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried
`.row.collapse`?

Answer (score 0):

.row.collapse makes margin equal to 0 not padding

Comment: This should be a comment on user2832344's answer.